# Geometrical interpretation of $ Im(z^4) \ge 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to ask you about a geometrical interpretation of the expression like $Im(z^4) \ge 0$.

What I did:

$Im [r^4(cos4α + isin4α] \ge 0$

$r^4sin4α ≥ 0$

$sin4α \ge  0$

$4\alpha = k \cdot \pi$, k is integer

$\alpha = k \cdot \frac{\pi}{4}$

But how to draw it on argand diagram? 
Is there any tool online? Is it possible on Wolfram Alpha?

Is it something like this?

[Geometrical interpretation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyVmm.gif)

Comment: Remember that to raise a complex number to an integer power, one raises the radius to that same power and multiplies the argument (angle) by that power. What if you first restrict $\alpha$ to some part of that $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ so that $0\le4\alpha\le\pi$, i.e. $z^4$ is in the upper half-plane (or on the real line)? Then add in multiples of $2\pi$ to $4\alpha$ - I see you tried something along those lines.

Comment: The result should be four equispaced infinite $45^\circ$ wedges emanating from the origin.

Comment: Is it something like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/FyVmm.gif Is there any way to draw something similar on Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: That's basically correct. The sectors extend to infinite radius, but that's a bit difficult to draw :-) I couldn't get Wolfram Alpha to draw anything reasonable - it doesn't seem to like inequalities involving complex numbers.

Comment: @Marconius, could you create an answer based on your comment? I found this way to draw it on WolframAlpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5BIm%5B%28a%20%2b%20I%20b%29%5E4%5D,%20%7Ba,%20-2,%202%7D,%20%7Bb,%20-2,%202%7D%5D

Comment: But... Why does it have light and dark parts? Is it possible to explain it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to [Marconius](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232988/marconius).

The plot was made with Mathematica:

```
ContourPlot[Im[(a + I b)^4], {b, a} \[Element] Disk[], 
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotPoints -> 50, 
   Contours -> #] & /@ {1, 5, 10}
```

[image]